# Creating groups on the Ribbon control in Visual Studio 2012 and WPF?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012

I have the following problem when I create groups with WPF and Ribbon control.
The image below explains the problem:

[image]

The code is:

```
<Window x:Class="Arelion.InternalProjects.RouteVisualization.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Route Visualization" Height="395" Width="832">
<Grid>
<Ribbon Name="ribbon">
<RibbonGroup Name="groupHome" Header="View">
<RibbonToggleButton Label="Display Map"/>
<RibbonToggleButton Label="Online"/>
</RibbonGroup>
</Ribbon>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Can you post your XAML? That's the ribbon bar... It looks like you've put your content into the ribbon tab area instead of the bar area

Comment: Yes sorry, I posted it now.

Comment: @user2381422, try putting your `RibbonGroup` within `RibbonTab`

Comment: @dkozl Can you please post your answer as reply so that I can accept it as answer? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclosing `RibbonGroup` within `RibbonTab` should solve your issue:

```
<Ribbon Name="ribbon">
   <RibbonTab>
      <RibbonGroup Name="groupHome" Header="View">
         <RibbonToggleButton Label="Display Map"/>
         <RibbonToggleButton Label="Online"/>
      </RibbonGroup>
   </RibbonTab>
</Ribbon>
```